# Fetching indexes of all selected elements in a select using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to fetch all the indexes of the selected items in a select. I want to put those indexes obtained , in an array. Here is my code:

```
var temparr=new Array();

$("#listbox option :selected").each(function(){
     temparr.push($(this).index()); 

});
alert(temparr);
```

This alert shows nothing. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are searching the `:selected` in descendants of option but not selected property of option. The `space` between `option` and `:selected` should be removed.

*Change*

```
$("#listbox option :selected")
```

*To*

```
$("#listbox option:selected")
```

Also use loop to iterate through the elements of array

```
for(i=0; i < temparr.length; i++)
   alert(temparr[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

There should not be any space between `option` & `:selected` because if it is there then it will act like an descendant selector(searches for an selected element that is a descendant of the `option` element)

```
$("#listbox option:selected")
//                ^ no space here
```